# How to load .so file (native lib) in Android targetSdkVersion 26 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am trying to load `so` file (which is a native C/C++ code that has already compiled) into my Android app, but it doesn't work(throwing exception and the app stops working).

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-685
>                                                                                     Process: com.dsyr.selftoidcardmatcherdemo, PID: 11990
>                                                                                     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

If I change targetSdkVersion to 21, then it is working well. So what is the reason that in targetSdkVersion 26 the lib cannot be load? Are there any extra things that we should do in version 26?

Comment: `" ... but it doesn't work"`, what does it mean?

Comment: @pskink now you can check again. it means that when loading the lib, the app stops working.

Comment: `"trowing exception"`, what exception? whats your code? how are you loding .so library?

Comment: @pskink you can check again

Comment: are you using `dlopen`? what is your code?  how are you loding .so library?

Comment: @pskink I am using Java, `System.loadLibrary("libname");` the same code is working in 21, but not in 26.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil take a look at this [behavior changes on Android-26](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#nl)

Comment: It's might be [writable/executable sgment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Writable-and-Executable-Segments-Enforced-for-API-level-26), or [using private libraries](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Private-API-Enforced-for-API-level-24). The latter has been around [since API 24](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk), but was not fully enforced for apps that targeted API 23 or older.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and I try this 
Delete all 64-bit libraries and left only 32-bit libs:

In Application[image].mk:

```
APP_API := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips
```

app gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
```

gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../cpp/native.cpp // your native c++ file
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../cpp/native-handler.h //if u have header File
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -llog -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It will use 32-bit library for 64-bit

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me where the Android.mk and gradle.properties files are located? And also my libs are all 32bit, there is no 64bit.